# SFTP with VB.NET - upload via server issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sftp

I've been working on a site to allow clients to sftp data files to us (using SharpSSH.dll) My solution works fine on my development machine but as soon as I move it to production server I am unable to upload.

I know that the problem is because my code is trying to pick up a file on the server when it obviously doesn't exist there so I need some pointers on the best way to resolve this - i.e. how do I adjust my code to allow for an sftp upload from the client machine?

The plan is basically to (and im not entirely sure that I am going about this the correct way) use my web server as a go-between so the client logs on and sftps a file to another server.  Advice and pointers are very welcomed - please see code below:

```
transfer = New SecureFileTransfer("IP", "PORT", "NAME", "PASSWORD")
    If transfer.putFile(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName, company & "/" & filename) = True Then
        lblMsg.Text = "File upload complete!"

        'write data file details to table
        writeAudit()

        'check which account manager to alert and send email notification
        emailNotify()
    Else
        lblMsg.Text = "File upload has failed - please try again..."
        Exit Sub
    End If



Public Sub New(ByVal hostname As String, ByVal port As Integer, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
    Me._hostname = hostname
    Me._port = port
    Me._username = username
    Me._password = password
End Sub



Public Function putFile(ByVal localFile As String, ByVal remotePath As String) As Boolean
    Try
        transfer = New Sftp(Me._hostname, Me._username, Me._password)
        transfer.Connect(Me._port)
        transfer.Put(localFile, remotePath)
        transfer.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\logfile.txt")
        objWriter.Write(ex.Message)
        objWriter.Close()

        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

I have checked my sftp credentials and made sure that access from my web server to sftp server is valid and working.  My log file is giving me the following exception message:

```
Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\x.txt'.
```

I think I may be misunderstanding how the FileUpload control works here which may well be the crux of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is but I would say that if you have tested your code and are happy it works, then this is not first place to start looking for problems. I would start with the configuration of the FTP server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me - I have only tested my code on my machine locally so the test upload file existed on the same machine as my code.  The problem is that the server can't see the upload file on the client machine so I need to find out how to (temporarily) securely move this file to the web server and then over to my SFTP server (hope that makes sense!)